# Problem temporarily disabling a EditText field

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to create an activity which gets input in the following form:

```
() Option 1  (a RadioButton)
() Option 2  (a RadioButton)
() Custom    (a RadioButton)
[     ]      (a EditText)
```

The idea is that the user can either choose one of the two predefined values, or enter a custom value. In order for him to enter a custom value, he must activate the "() Custom" RadioButton.

```
<EditText 
  android:id="@+id/CustomValue"
  android:text="" 
  android:enabled="false"
  android:inputType="phone"
  android:digits="0123456789." />
```

The problem is the following

When this code is executed, before the "() Custom" RadioButton is checked, the EditText appears in a shaded color (unlike the ones which do not have enable=false). However, if the TextView is clicked, the input keyboard is displayed and it accepts input.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think at the moment this is an issue and has been reported to Android as a bug.

You can set the EditText as:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

This won't allow the user to select the field to type into it.

Alternatively you could set the field to:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

or:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Then change the visibility to visible.

See the following for more details:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2771

Comment: Note: When enabling it in code use setFocusableInTouchMode(true) as setFocusable(true) doesn't reanable it as you would expect - see comment 7 on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should also set [`android:focusable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3afocusable) to `false` so the text field is not selected automatically. But don't forget to set it to `true` again if you enable it. ;-)